# How to create a desktop only website using html5-boilerplate?

Tags: css, html, meta, html5boilerplate

I used to start my work using [html5-boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) instead of creating file from scratch. It is awesome for responsive web design.

I am developing a [non-responsive website](http://pearwalknew.droolingfrog.co.uk/) and client needs desktop version for mobiles too (remember how websites opens on mobile few years ago).

I did not make it responsive and do not add any styles in media queries.

I works fine on desktops but when we see the website on a mobile device(or less 940 px wide screens) it does not show complete backgrounds of full width containers(i.e. 100%) instead it only show the [background according to width of device](http://screencast.com/t/wGLnPZkwbll).

I am not sure but I think there is problem in following code which is meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I removed this code and test the website but problem remains. Can any one please tell me the solution?

***Note:** I have build the most of site and now I can not write markup from scratch.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an easiest possible solution to this and its working for me. I just added following code into CSS file (my media query section of at bottom of main.css in case html boilerplate).

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    /* Style adjustments for non responsive websites */
    body{width:940px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Why maximum-scale=1? Don't you think it will made user unable to zoom in?

Comment: Yeah it does - include it if you want your scale settings to remain consistent when switching orientations on mobile devices. But if you don't - try without but still include initial-scale.

Comment: It does not work and its because the element I have has a width of 100%.